# What does Community Wiki (CW) mean?

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki

There are several questions (like [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-are-beginner-role-playing-table-top-games)) that say `community wiki`. Also there are random answers that say `community wiki` even though the questions they answer don't (like [this one](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5025/which-systems-use-the-cthulhu-mythos/5136#5136)).

What does `community wiki` mean?

Comment: There are a lot of CW question on meta, but many of them are no longer relevant - ever since CW became a mod-only feature - or somewhat localized and unclear. Hopefully this question can clear things up for new users.

Comment: It _used to be_ a user option on questions. See http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/630/where-did-the-community-wiki-option-go

Answer (score 6):

Basically, they are posts that are owned by the community with a much lower reputation threshold for editing. They are sometimes used when the poster wants others to collaborate and add to their answer and improve it, such as this one.

---

From the [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) (on http://meta.stackoverflow.com):

> - Community Wiki posts are owned by the Community User, not by any individual user.
> - A much lower reputation (100 instead of 2000) is needed to edit a community wiki post.
> - Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation.
> - The original author still gets badges based on community posts.
> - The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their post entered community mode.

A post (question or answer) becomes community wiki if one of the following is true:

- It has more than 30 answers.
- The owner has edited the post 10 times (tag edits don't count).
- 5 different users have edited it (again, tag edits don't count).
- It's flagged for moderator attention and a moderator enables the community wiki mode (typically done only by request).

An answer is made community wiki:

- if the owner check the box when creating or editing it.
- if it is posted to a question that is already community wiki.

---

You can [find all posts that are community wiki](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1) by using the [Advanced Ninja Search Option](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=) `wiki:1`.